# How can I get a sample of my input data for testing purposes using Talend?

Tags: talend

Is there a component in the Talend Open Studio edition (or else, the Enterprise edition) that allows one to do a test run of a job? I would like to do a test load of a small batch of data.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you could just provide less data as the input. So this could be to manually provide a small test input file or change your query to use `LIMIT` (or your RDBMS' equivalent) or even add some filtering criteria in the query to a database or in a tFilterRow component.

Alternatively you can use the [tSampleRow](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tSampleRow) component to take a sample of your input data.

Comment: Yes, I did this. Just wasn't sure if there wasn't something else I was missing.